# How do I enable a "contextual" editor in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, editor, visual-studio-extensions

A number of IDEs and editors are offering "contextual" editing tools:

- A simple example is the [Assistant Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/040-Edit_Source_Code/edit_source_code.html) In XCode. A secondary edit windows automatically loads a relevant secondary file depending on which context you are in. For instance, if you open a header (`foo.h`) in the primary window, it automatically opens the implementation (`foo.m`) in the assistant window, and so on.

[image: XCode's Assistant Editor]

- Brackets has [Quick Edit](http://brackets.io/) where pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> allows you to edit the CSS selector that points to your current HTML element.

  [image: Brackets' Quick Edit]
- [Light Table](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/306316578/light-table) has inline documentation and drafting tables:

  [image: Light Table's inline documentation]

  [image: Light Table's drafting tables]
- Microsoft has a [Debugger Canvas](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4a979842-b9aa-4adf-bfef-83bd428a0acb) project that is similar to what I want, but it's debug mode only and limited to Visual Studio Ultimate. The tool I am looking for is a tool for coding, not debugging.

  [image: Microsoft's Debugger Canvas]

I would like a normal editor, and a secondary editor that shows me the context of what I am currently editing.

- If I am on a class that implements an interface, I would like the secondary editor to show the interface
- If I am on a class member that is an instance of another class, I would like the secondary editor to switch to the class source
- If I am on a method, I would like the secondary editor to point to the method body

and so on…

**Is there a way<sup>(*)</sup> to have a similar experience in Visual Studio 2012?**

<sup>(*) some hidden trick, an extension feature, a quick hack, a solution that works for you…</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Code Definition window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5yx24a6(v=vs.80).aspx).

You enable it by going to `View > Code Definition Window`. You can then dock it on the middle right. It works like so:

[image: Code Definition]

Comment: and from within that window you can right-click->Edit Definition (or assign that to a shortcut) to open a text editor for it

Comment: @stijn: After right-click you must select "Go To Definition " not "Edit Definition"

Comment: @JesonPark not exactly, it depends on what you want.. `Edit Definition` will take you to the definition of the symbol that is under the cursor of the `editor`, hence the symbol that is used to define what gets displayed in the Code Definition Window. `Go To Definition` does what it always does so it will take you to the definition of the symbol under the cursor of the `Code Definition Window`. Might be the same, depening on where your cursor is.